# How to change the nanomsg pipeline load balancing logic?

Tags: load-balancing, zeromq, nanomsg

I'm hoping to use something like **`nanomsg`** (or **`ZeroMQ`**). Specifically the pipeline pattern. Instead of a round-robin method for sending out the data, I would like to load balance based on the data.
**Any suggestions?**

Comment: @user3666197 According to this link: stackoverflow.com/help/mcve "When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem." In my case there is no code to show because I had a general question about how best to create a content based router using either nanomsg or ZeroMQ. I am very **passionate** about StackOverflow and have been a member for over 6 years. **I'm sorry if you felt offended.**

Comment: @user3666197 For my own reference, did someone from the community flag my question for moderator review? Or did you just decide to pick on my question for some reason? According to [A Theory on Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/): "...moderators **occasionally** need to intervene. Moderators are human **exception handlers**, there to deal with those (hopefully **rare**) exceptional conditions that should not normally happen..." Have you ever considered that your **exceptionally** lengthy criticism of questions actually turns away users of the service?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ZMQ sockets with custom load-balancing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20649709/zmq-sockets-with-custom-load-balancing)

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to the **ZeroMQ** use case here: [ZMQ sockets with custom load-balancing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20649967/118999)

Ultimately though, I think what I was really looking for was better served with a DDS solution as opposed to **ZeroMQ** or **nanomsg**. I found this question and answer very helpful: [WHY / WHEN using rather DDS instead of ZeroMQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27772931/118999)